# google map api v2 and minimum android target version supported

Tags: java, android, google-maps

What is the minimum version and how can I build app for provided I am using google v2 maps, currently in eclipse project > right click, android target it shows minimum as 4.0

Comment: it is supported from `api-8` android 2.2 using `SupportMapFragment`

Comment: thanks Kaushik, why does it only show me android 4.0 as minimum target version ?

Comment: check your manifest file for `android:minSdkVersion` value

Comment: `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />`

Answer (score 2):

Import `google-play-services_lib` into Eclipse as a **library projet** into **same workspace** create a project and add `google-play-services_lib` as **library**. Then do like this

XML layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yourpackage.name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.yourpackage.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.yourpackage.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.yourpackage.name.SupportMapFragmentActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="Google-Play-API-Key-Here-which-u-have-generated" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Java code

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class SupportMapFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_support_map_fragment);

 FragmentManager fmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
 SupportMapFragment supportmapfragment = (SupportMapFragment)fmanager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);;
 GoogleMap map = supportmapfragment.getMap();

 } 
}
```

Comment: ok in short I added `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />` to my manifest file and now I cleaned and built the project and then if I right click and properties and goto android menu, it shows target name as android 4.0 minimum

Comment: that was for which version u want to compile with

Comment: so how can I make it runnable in android 2.3 ?

Comment: it will run in android 2.3 devices as *minSdkVersion* is 8

Comment: but why the android target name is being shown as `4.0` ?

Comment: when u create project in eclipse u set `compile with` option to `API14:Android 4.0(ICS)` thats why it is showing when you right click on project and properties and goto android menu, it shows target name as android 4.0. It is not minimum version.

Comment: no need to worry about that ur application will run on those devices too which have android-2.2